# Cannot read Chinese Char from SQL into R

Tags: sql, r, collation

I have a DB with Chinese collation (type: Chinese_PRC_CI_AS). When i read this DB into Rstudio, all the Characters becomes ????. I tried changing System Locale to Chinese settings (Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL",locale="chinese") but still doesn't work. Any ideas?

SQL DB: 
[Columns in SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCM81.jpg)

[Columns in RStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuuEq.jpg)

I've searched the internet to no avail.

Thanks in advance

To provide more information, i'm using mssql, and sessionInfo() is:

R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCM81.jpg) LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936  LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936

attached base packages:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCM81.jpg) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCM81.jpg) RMySQL_0.10.9     DBI_0.5-1         date_1.2-36       data.table_1.10.4 stringr_1.1.0     ggplot2_2.2.1     RODBC_1.3-14      zoo_1.7-14        chron_2.3-49
[10] plyr_1.8.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCM81.jpg) Rcpp_0.12.9      lattice_0.20-34  assertthat_0.1   grid_3.2.5       gtable_0.2.0     magrittr_1.5     scales_0.4.1     stringi_1.1.2    lazyeval_0.2.0
[10] tools_3.2.5      munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.3-2 tibble_1.2

Comment: please specify database ?  mysql or mssql or Oracle

Comment: see if you can set the default font in rstudio.  Set "Chinese" font as default and see if it is showing correctly

Comment: Try changing encoding of the DB while importing it to R studio

Comment: Thanks Ayush. I'm not sure that is the approach I think somehow the encoding that is used to read in the SQL table should be specified but I can't find one that works

Comment: For MySQL, see "question marks" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

```
 select * from table where [conditions]
 [remaining query]
 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT;
```

use this last line to get the req collation.

Comment: Thanks Ahsen. I tried this but still not working. I also tried to specify DBMSsencoding to UTF-8 and still do not work